# PHP crawler to collect comments on articles

Tags: php, web-scraping, mysqli

I have code that parses through web pages finds commentaries and saves commentary info in DB. I have an array where all necessary pages are stored. I iterate through all these pages one by one and find HMTL element which contains all the info about commentary if there are multiple pages with commentaries I iterate through all of them. I also check each word spelling with dictionary and calculate correctness of the whole commentary. Then I save all the info + some additional info into my DB. I am using Simple HTML DOM parser.

The code is messy and quite slow and I would like to speed it up by optimizing it.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=Windows-1252');
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

include('connect.php');
set_time_limit(0);
include('simple_html_dom.php');

//array with links to pages
$array = array();

foreach ($array as $value){

$nextLink = $value;

// Parse each link
while ($nextLink) {

        //finds class with commentary info 
        $html=file_get_html($nextLink);
        $articles = $html->find('div [class=article-comment]');

            // iterate throught each commentary class
            foreach($articles as $article) {

                // finds commentary text     
                $content = $article->find('div[class=article-comment-content]',0)->innertext;

                // Dictionary
                $broker = enchant_broker_init();
                $tag = 'lv_LV';


                enchant_broker_set_dict_path($broker, ENCHANT_MYSPELL, 'C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12');

                 //check spellnig of each word
                if (enchant_broker_dict_exists($broker, $tag)) {
                        $dict = enchant_broker_request_dict($broker, $tag);

                    //skip elements for check                                                                 
                        $trimmed_str = str_replace(['.', ',', '?', '!', ':', '"',')', '(', '*', '-', '–','','+','-','%',';',"'",'=','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','/'], ' ', $content);
                        $word_count = str_word_count($trimmed_str, 0, 'ēūīāšģķļžčņĒŪĪĀŠĢĶĻŽČŅ');
                        $word_array = preg_split('/\s+/', $trimmed_str);                                                 

                            //corect words count
                            $correct_words = 0;

                            //array for incorrect words
                            $incorrect_words = array();

                            //check words, if incorrect -> add to the array else add to count 1
                            foreach ($word_array as $word_value ){

                                $isCorrectlySpelled = enchant_dict_check($dict, $word_value);

                                    if ($isCorrectlySpelled !== true) {                              
                                    array_push($incorrect_words, $word_value);
                                } 

                                else {

                                    $correct_words +=1;
                                }
                            }

                            //incorrect words are stored in the array and separated with comma
                            $comma_separated = implode(",", $incorrect_words);

                            //calclate corectness of each word
                            $correctness = round(($correct_words/$word_count)*100,2);
                }
                enchant_broker_free($broker);


                // author of commentary
                $author = $article->find('strong[class=article-comment-author]',0)->innertext;       
                $date = $article->find('time[datetime]',0)->outertext;


                $str = $html->getElementById("someId")->outertext;
                $var = preg_split('/datetime=\"/', $date);
                $var1 = preg_split('/\"/',$var[1]);

                //likes and dislikes
                $voteUP = $article->find('a[class=article-comment-vote plus]',0)->innertext;
                $voteDown = $article->find('a[class=article-comment-vote minus]',0)->innertext;



                    //save info in DB
                    $sql = strip_tags("INSERT INTO commentstable(comment, author, date, VoteUP, VoteDown, word_count, correct_words, correctness, incorrect, articleID) VALUES ('$content', '$author', '$var1[0]', '$voteUP', '$voteDown','$word_count','$correct_words', '$correctness', '$comma_separated', '')"); 

                        if($sql) {                                               
                            if(mysqli_query($connection, $sql)){
                                echo "Records added successfully.";
                            } 
                            else{
                                echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $insert. " . mysqli_error($link);
                            }
                        }
            }

            //If there are no more pages with comments
            $next_stop = $html->find('a[class=pageing-button-next disable]',0);

            if($next_stop){
                break;                           
            }

            // open next page
            $nextLink = ( ($temp = $html->find("a[class=pageing-button-next]", 0)) ? "http://somepage.com".$temp->href : NULL );

            // Clear DOM object
            $html->clear();         
            unset($html);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are open to SQL injection. If a site knows that you scrape it they can put an SQL injection payload into their HTML. An attacker can for example read out data from sensitive tables and insert it into the commentstable. If you display the gathered information in a HTML page and don't properly sanitize it before displaying it, an attacker could then also use XSS to send the collected information to their server. Depending on the db rights, an attacker might also be able to read and write files, thus gaining code execution.

It is never ok to put variables directly into queries. You should always use prepared statements.

In addition to the security aspect, your current approach will also break as soon as a single quote is in the data.

- Why do you call `strip_tags` on the query? It may break your data and doesn't serve any purpose.
- You need more functions. Having one large block that does multiple things is hard to read and hard to maintain. At the very least you want `insertComment($db, $content, $author, ...)`, `spellCheck($content)`, and `parseHTML($html)`. Now, you could profile the different methods and see where your performance problem actually is (my guess would be that the bottleneck is the network connection, in which case multi-threading is the only solution; but it may well be that the spellcheck is the bottleneck; but we can't know that without profiling).

Answer (score 0):

I would set the script up to accept a single GET parameter that is the array item (URL). Create a simple html page that loops through the array of URL's and performs an Ajax request to the script you have passing it the URL from the loop.

This will "parallel" the work. Browser caps number of concurrent Ajax requests, but it'll still be a LOT faster.